# SOCKS5: Connection not allowed by ruleset, when connect SFTP with SSH.NET and a proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, sftp, ssh.net

When connect SFTP with SSH.NET and a proxy i get this error when connect :

```
KO > Exception :
    Message :  'SOCKS5: Connection not allowed by ruleset.'
    StackTrace :
           at Renci.SshNet.Connection.Socks5Connector.HandleProxyConnect(IConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Socket socket)
   at Renci.SshNet.Connection.Socks5Connector.Connect(IConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.CreateAndConnectSession()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
   at Debug.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\DEV\ruche\Debug\Program.cs:line 17
```

With FileZilla everything works with the sames parameters.
Don't know what i'm missing....

Here is my code sample :

```
 public SftpClient GetClient()
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Proxy_Adresse) == false)
     {
         ConnectionInfo lInfos = new ConnectionInfo(Adresse, //My SFTP adresse
                                               Port,  // 22 
                                               Username, //My SFTP User
                                               ProxyTypes.Socks5,
                                               Proxy_Adresse,
                                               Proxy_Port, //1080
                                               Proxy_Username, //empty in my case
                                               Proxy_Password, //empty in my case
                                               new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(Username, Password)); //My SFTP User / Password

         return new SftpClient(lInfos);

     }
     else
     {
         return new SftpClient(Adresse, Port, Username, Password);
     }
 }
```

```
using (var lClient = lSFTP.GetClient())
{
    lClient.Connect();
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

Comment: Complete exception callstack please. Your FileZilla configuration might be also helpful. Can you connect with any other client (possibly some that does better logging than FileZilla)?

Comment: Hi, i,have update main post with the stacktrace, also put the config of fileZilla in second post.

for the question > yes i can connect with other like winscp, i will do a batch script  running winscp rather than ssh.net in c# but it will be in last resort.